# Proving two equivalent propositions

Tags: logic

Prove that the propositional formulas:

```
    P OR Q OR R
```

and

```
(P AND NOT(Q)) OR (Q AND NOT(R)) OR (R AND NOT(P)) OR (P AND Q AND R)
```

are equivalent.

I have tried De Morgan's Laws and Distributive Laws on the right hand side, but I got some formulas that are even more complicated.

Comment: What rules/methods do you know for such propositional formulae? e.g. Distributive rules, De Morgan's laws...

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE!  When posting a question, you need to include all your work and specifically where you are stuck. Otherwise people will explain too much or too little.  Also, you can learn the math formatting for MSE here:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I know De Morgan's Laws, Distribute Laws

Comment: My hint to begin with would be to consider (P AND NOT(Q)) OR (P AND Q AND R) and show this is equivalent to P AND (NOT(Q) OR R) which is equivalent to (P AND NOT(Q)) OR (P AND R). Rinse and repeat this for the other ones then it should drop out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was taught this as someone who did electronics, I have a differing notation that has stuck with me. Here $+$ denotes OR, $\cdot$ denotes AND and $\overline{P}$ represents not $P$ etc. Apologies for the inconsistency it just works better in my head. One can show this using distributivity laws only.

Note that

$$ P\cdot \overline{Q} + P\cdot Q \cdot R = P\cdot(\overline{Q}+Q\cdot R)=P\cdot (\overline{Q} + R) = P\cdot \overline{Q}+ P\cdot R$$

Similarly,

$$ Q\cdot \overline{R} + P\cdot Q \cdot R =Q\cdot \overline{R}+ Q\cdot P$$

and

$$ R\cdot \overline{P} + P\cdot Q \cdot R =R\cdot \overline{P}+ R\cdot Q.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{split}P\cdot \overline{Q}+ Q\cdot \overline{R}+ R\cdot \overline{P} + P\cdot Q \cdot R & = P\cdot \overline{Q}+ P\cdot Q \cdot R+ Q\cdot \overline{R}+ P\cdot Q \cdot R+ R\cdot \overline{P} + P\cdot Q \cdot R \\ &= P\cdot \overline{Q}+ P\cdot R + Q\cdot \overline{R}+ Q\cdot P+R\cdot \overline{P}+ R\cdot Q \\ & = P+Q+R\end{split}$$

as desired.

You could also just use a truth table but that is not so elegant.